# Magento 2.2.2 - Adding Product to Wishlist doesn't work when user is not logged in

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist, magento2.2.2, custom-theme

Using `Custom Theme`, when user is not logged in and try to add a product to wishlist, it is served up the login or create an account screen. Once the user logs in, the item user was trying to add to wishlist isn't appearing under `My Wishlist` in `Account Dashboard` and it says `You have no items in your wish list.` So now user has to go back and add.

Although when user is logged in and then try to add a product to wishlist, its working.

How do I add the product upon login?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11825

Answer (score 2):

I have patch for this issue. You need to override these two files.

1. `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Helper/Data.php`
2. `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Observer/CustomerLogin.php`

**Override `Data.php` and `CustomerLogin.php` with di.xml**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Helper\Wishlist\Data" />
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Observer\CustomerLogin" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Observer\Wishlist\CustomerLogin" />
</config>
```

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Helper/Wishlist/Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper\Wishlist;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\FormKey as PageCacheFormKey;
use Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;


class Data extends \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
{
    /**
     * Refresh and set new form_key in session and cookie
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function refreshFormKey()
    {
        $beforeWishlistRequest = $this->_customerSession->getBeforeWishlistRequest();

        if ($beforeWishlistRequest !== null) {

            $formKeyData = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(FormKey::class);

            //form_key is already empty
            $formKey = $formKeyData->getFormKey();

            $sessionConfig = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ConfigInterface::class);
            $cookieMetadata = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CookieMetadataFactory::class)->createPublicCookieMetadata();
            $cookieMetadata->setDomain($sessionConfig->getCookieDomain());
            $cookieMetadata->setPath($sessionConfig->getCookiePath());
            $cookieMetadata->setDuration($sessionConfig->getCookieLifetime());

            ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(PageCacheFormKey::class)->set(
                $formKey,
                $cookieMetadata
            );

            $beforeWishlistRequest['form_key'] = $formKey;
            $this->_customerSession->setBeforeWishlistRequest($beforeWishlistRequest);
            $this->_customerSession->setBeforeRequestParams($beforeWishlistRequest);
            $this->_customerSession->setBeforeModuleName('wishlist');
            $this->_customerSession->setBeforeControllerName('index');
            $this->_customerSession->setBeforeAction('add');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now remove generated folder and flush cache

Comment: Hello, how to add wish-list for guest customer ?

Comment: @Prince patel can you please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256222/magento-2-2-3-ce-unable-to-add-remove-item-from-wishlist

Comment: @Prince, It is redirecting to wishlist page after login but not adding item into wishlist