# Magento 2.2.3 CE unable to add/remove item from wishlist?

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart, wishlist

We are getting facing an error message when we add (or) remove item from wishlist in magento 2.2.3 CE can you please advise? ? we didn't write any custom code from custom module.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on
>   boolean in
>   /srv/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Observer/Customer/RemoveWishlistItem.php:52
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72):
>   Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Observer\Customer\RemoveWishlistItem->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))

```
1 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(60): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Observer\Customer\RemoveWishlistItem), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) 
2 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) 
3 /srv/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('wishlist_item_d...', Array)
4 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/Abstract in /srv/public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Observer/Customer/RemoveWishlistItem.php on line 52
```

- https://prnt.sc/m23ybx

Comment: please write your code here.

Comment: @AasimGoriya  i didn't write any custom code  related to wishlist and emails

Comment: @AasimGoriya  may be i am facing an issue with  'Dotdigitalgroup_Email' this module

Comment: @NagarajuKasa Any Solutions?