# In Magento 2 handler catalog_category_default , catalog_category_layered not present

Tags: magento2

What are the replacements for above in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

`catalog_category_view_type_default` is alternavtive of `catalog_category_default`

And `catalog_category_view_type_layered` is alternative of `catalog_category_layered`

Comment: can you recheck your answer as I had just verified mines and catalog_category_view_type_default.xml is responsible for adding/removing the layer navigation.

Comment: I'm also looking deep into it. give me few minutes

Comment: hi @amit can u help on this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256222/magento-2-2-3-ce-unable-to-add-remove-item-from-wishlist

Answer (score 0):

In magento following equivalents to above:

```
catalog_category_layered.xml => catalog_category_view_type_layered.xml
catalog_category_default.xml => catalog_category_view_type_default.xml
```